# How to get the size of a UTF-16LE string in bytes?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Say I have the following:

```
wchar_t *str = L"Hello World!";
```

I want to get the size of `L"Hello World!"` in bytes (not how many characters it consists of).

I have read that `wcslen()` counts every 2 bytes as 1 character, so if a character is 4 bytes, it will treat it as 2 characters!

This is great for me because now I can just do:

```
int size_of_str_in_bytes = wcslen(str) * 2;
```

But is it guaranteed that `wcslen()` will always behave this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `wcslen` always gives you the number of `wchar_t`s. It's the analogue of `strlen`.

(Note that, just like `strlen`, the terminating "null" character is *not* included!)

That's not quite the same as *"counting every 2 bytes as 1 character"*, though for systems on which `wchar_t` is 2 bytes wide, the effect would be the same.

I would use `sizeof(wchar_t)` instead of `2`, though. Y'know, for portability and all that.

For example, Coliru's platform has `sizeof(wchar_t) == 4`:

```
#include <cwchar>
#include <cassert>

int main()
{
    const wchar_t* wstr = L"Hello world";
    const size_t size_of_wide_cstr_in_bytes = wcslen(wstr) * sizeof(wchar_t);

    assert(sizeof(wchar_t) == 4);             // on this particular system
    assert(size_of_wide_cstr_in_bytes == 44); // on this particular system
}
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e54c4de418c8bacc))

Comment: [Here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/22848371#22848371) is the reason. (I took back my downvote)

Comment: @khajvah: That is an abuse of your voting privileges. One might even call it voting fraud... I believe one month's suspension is the traditional punishment for such a crime!